# Does the Ghoul sorcerer bloodline arcana heal when you cast a spell or when deal damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The ghoul sorcerer bloodline arcana states,
"Whenever you cast a spell of the necromancy school that deals hit point damage, you are healed of 1 hit point per spell level."

Does this happen when you cast the necromancy spell or is it only when you deal damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The spell must *both* be cast *and* deal hp damage

The [ghoul sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/ghoul-sorcerer-bloodline) bloodline arcana says that

> Whenever you cast a spell of the necromancy school that deals hit point damage, you are healed of 1 hit point per spell level.

That means for each necromancy spell *both* that's cast *and* that deals damage, the sorcerer heals 1 hp per spell level. *And* it means that the effect occurs only *once* upon each iteration of *both* casting the spell *and* dealing hp damage with that spell.

For example, the first time the sorcerer deals at least 1 hp of damage with the spell [*chill touch*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chill-touch) after the spell's cast, the sorcerer heals 1 hp of damage due to his bloodline arcana, but on the second and successive touches with the same *chill touch* spell, the sorcerer heals no further hp damage.

For example, when the sorcerer casts [*wail of the banshee*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wail-of-the-banshee), if he deals with that spell at least 1 hp of damage, he heals 9 hp of damage due to his bloodline arcana, but he won't heal *more* than that 9 hp of damage, no matter how many creatures the *wail* damages.

Comment: Note that, as spells can deal hit point damage to inanimate objects, you can still use this arcana to (inefficiently) heal yourself while there are no hostile targets around.

Comment: @GMJoe Necromancy spells that damage objects are rare, though. However, given that this bloodline arcane is really sad, I'd totally house rule that *just* casting the spell is sufficient to heal hp damage: "Man, guys," says the Sor18, "I wish Grond hand't killed that last kobold 'cause then I could have damaged it with my *wail of the banshee* and healed **nine** hit points. Guess I'll just have to wait." Worst resource manager *ever.*

Comment: Fair point on most necromancy spells only working on living things. Still, a lot of the time there's at least some immobile plants or wall fungus nearby; I suspect a fair few GMs are generous enough to let those count.

Comment: Sands of time is a necromancy spell that deals damage to undead and objects but not to living creatures.

Comment: @Umbranus Rare indeed! The existence of *sands of time*, however, I don't think makes the ghoul sorcerer bloodline arcana much better. It's still only 3 hp of healing in exchange for zapping a crowbar with a 3rd-level spell. `:-)`